# How to release/publish iOS app through VSTS

Tags: ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using VSTS for build and release for the iOS and Android applications created through Xamarin. Releasing the Android app to the store is relatively simple through VSTS. Can someone guid me or provide some steps of how to release the app into the appstore through VSTS.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not answering your question, but great reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/10/18/building-ios-apps-in-tfs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Play](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) to publish your Android app easily from VSTS. But for iOS app, there isn't any task can do this for now. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

Answer (score 2):

Now its availabe on the vsts marketplace. Check out:
[Apple App Store - VSTS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store)